# Postgres Join Query

Tags: postgresql, join

I have two tables and I want to get an output from both tables from a single query. Below is the output of each table.

```
**select email,id  from people;**

        email                |             id
-----------------------------+------------------------------
 user1@gmail.com             |            uid1
 user2@gmail.com             |            uid2

**select user,date  from company;**

        user                 |             date
-----------------------------+------------------------------
 uid1                        |            2021.1.1
 uid2                        |            2021.2.3
```

I want an output which consists the date and email address. I tried some JOIN queries but didn't work.

**id (people table) and user (company table) are equal.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly suspected, a JOIN is the way to go:

```
select p.id, p.email, c.date
from people p
  join company c on c."user" = p.id;
```

Comment: what's p? p.id? p.email?

Comment: You specify 'p' as 'people' table right? But what if both table starts from letter 'p'? Example 'people' and 'pupil'? - Just and example only

Comment: `p` is a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES) - you can choose whatever name you like as the alias